# French drain with no swale

Tags: landscaping, french-drain

My backyard is relatively flat and I like that but we get a lot of water running toward our house after heavy rains and filling up the window wells and making a swamp in the backyard. Some landscapers have suggested regrading and putting a swale there with a french drain running down the middle but I would hate to lose the flatness and the distance from the back of the house to the fence isn't that big.

The run would be something close to 100 feet to cover the whole back of the house and I'm wondering if we can still have the french drain but without adding the swale. Keep the flat yard but let the drain slowly drop over that distance. Or is that not practical?

EDIT:

There is a storm sewer in the front of the house which is the east side. The west side gets water pushing up against that side of the house and it comes from the rest of the subdivision which sits slightly higher. I'm at the end. The north side has adequate slope toward the storm sewer. So they want to put a swale in the middle of the yard on the west side sloping toward the north side.

Comment: Where would either the swale or the french drain conduct the water to? Directly into the public storm sewer system or onto private property? To make clear my bias I strongly prefer surface drainage, i.e., a swale. A swale is cheaper and one can see if it is getting filled with sediment. A french drain is much more expensive, is really a professional job, and then what if the french drain plugs up or is insufficient?

Comment: Why do you prefer a flat backyard?

Comment: Is the water you want to drain away coming from your roof and from rainfall onto your yard or is it coming from uphill off your property?

Comment: I think they are recommending the swale for a place to drain to. You might consider adding one or more drywells to drain the French drain to and that would keep your back yard flat. 

Comment: @JimStewart For baseball, football and soccer.

Comment: So you cannot have a swale in the middle of the yard. How about on one edge? If the yard is flat but has some slope you could put a swale on the low side of the yard and have a set of parallel underground drains (aka french drains)  slope down into the swale.  How are natural turf soccer fields drained in a wet climate? Simultaneous drainage away from the house and from a flat yard is going to be an "interesting" design.

Comment: Where is this located?

Comment: @JimStewart Just finished with a landscaper who suggested doing that; put a french drain along the edge of the yard near the house, exiting on the north side where the slope is toward the storm sewer. We're in St. Louis.

Comment: St Louis . . . so poorly draining clay soil and lots of rain? Soccer and baseball in the back yard will work when the kids are young, but very soon I would think they would outgrow an average urban lot at least for baseball. I have seen some large "estate" properties in Dallas with a full batting cage and lights. When my baseball playing nephew was young we went down to a park at the end of the street, but there was no backstop so missed balls would go through poison ivy and down into a creek.  Also one had to watch for walkers creeping up who could get hit with an errant baseball.

Comment: What size is the entire property and what size is the backyard?

Comment: @JimStewart Well, I have a third of an acre in west county if you're familiar with the area. I'm warming up to grandkids in a few years I'm told.

Comment: If you're at the downhill end of a block, a french drain might help but it may not be enough.  It can direct water you see flowing across the surface.  But you also get water soaking into the ground all along the way.  At the low end, the water table can be high enough to affect your basement (it's below the depth of a french drain).  The french drain would be the first step, and keep your fingers crossed.  But be prepared for a phase 2 if it isn't enough.  Been there, done that.

Comment: @fixer1234 Water will not soak into the ground or cause any issues.

Comment: Are you saying it isn't a problem in your location or it can't happen at all?  I was in exactly your situation in a previous house and that turned out to be what was going on (the eventual solution was interior).  I see similar action in my current house just because the water table is normally fairly high relative to the basement and my house is next to a water catchment area.  In rainy periods, the table rises and my sump system runs continuously for days.  In long periods of dry weather, the table drops and the sump system may not even run in response to a storm.

Comment: In my area, water leaks coming up from the floor/wall are from hydrostatic pressure from water rising from underneath. This problem is from surface water flowing on top of the ground coming from higher elevations in the subdivision toward a storm sewer. The basement issue will be resolved with a sump pump. The surface water is what I'm trying to resolve.